# Returning integers from a string of different chars

Tags: java

I am having issues printing this string correctly. 
"34+23 * 15 +-10 // ** =?=". 
It is stored in a variable called String input;
I am trying to separate each of the different variable types to different tokens.
So for example, if i find integers i group them, if i find symbols, i group them.

I did a check for integers of 2 digits. But i am having problems doing checks for integers  of XX,XXX,XXXX. Meaning integers of different digits and not just two digits

```
if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && Characted.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1)){ //checking for integers
    count++;
    temp = input.substring(input.charAt(i), input.charAt(i+1));
    count = Integer.parseInt(temp);

    continue;   
}
```

Comment: If you always have natural numbers, then read each digit and add it to a String until you find a non-digit character (`+` or ` ` etc.). Convert that to an integer, if that happens. It isn't pretty code, but it might help you to solve your task.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [regular expressions](http://www.regexr.com/). This is an example of how to extract numbers out of a string:

```
      List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
      while (matcher.find()) {
         numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group()));
```

This even works for negative numbers and if I am not mistaken decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to write a `for` loop?

```
int j; // Declaration outside for, so the variable persists
for(j = i; Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j)); ++j); // Semicolon to do nothing in the loop, besides increasing j.
if(j > i)
{
    count = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, j));
    continue;
}
```

I left out the `count++` because you're overriding it anyway, not sure what you intended to do there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here. You could modify the method you are using. If you save the number so far and do:

```
String numberSofar = "";
for(char c : inputString){
   if(Character.isDigit(c)
      numberSoFar+=c;
   else{
      digits+= Integer.parseInt(c);
   }
}
```

Something like that will work, but it has a few draw backs. It's quite verbiose and it is quite slow (which probably won't matter unless you have millions of numbers but still...).

Another option is to use regex.

```
  int sum = 0;
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  while (matcher.find()) {
     sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
```

However, if you actually want to get the things that isn't numbers it gets a little more complex (or you could do two loops and just look for the opposite of what you looked for the first time. ^ will allow you to do that.